# C# send/receive from socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I want to send and receive some data from my server, but I don't know how to do this...

Basically I want to:
Send:
"some string"
To:
IP: 10.100.200.1
Port: 30000

Receive/read the response

Can someone give me some basic example or point me to a simple (working) tutorial?

Comment: Try the search feature: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sockets+c%23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple synchronous TcpClient sending a text string and receiving a text string.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

public class SimpleTcpClient {

    public static void Main() {

        TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();            
        tcpclnt.Connect("10.100.200.1",30000);

        String textToSend = "HelloWorld!";
        Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = asen.GetBytes(textToSend);

        stm.Write(data,0,data.Length);

        //You might want to wait a bit for an answer (Thread.Sleep or simething)

        byte[] responseData = new byte[1024];
        string textRecevided = "";
        int read = 0;               
        do {  
            read = stm.Read(responseData, 0, responseData.Length);
            for (int i=0; i < read; i++)
            {
                textRecevided += (char)responseData[i];
            }           
        } while (read > 0);

        Console.Write(textRecevied);

        tcpclnt.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I will work on your solution, and when something won't work, I will ask you :)

Comment: I've implemented this example in my code and the read takes a minute. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit broad and it could easily be answered by googling.

The thing that you are looking for is called a `Socket`. But in your case I would use a `TcpClient` since it makes the handling a bit easier.

Google "`TcpClient` c#" and you'll find some nice examples. Then come back with more specific questions if you can't get stuff working.